# unable to execute shell script as a user

Tags: linux

I've created one script for environment setup. I need Oracle to be installed as part of the script. below is the script i've written (pardon for errors, i'm new). The problem is, when i executed it, they are running fine individually, but collectively, the script is exiting and failing after "UNZIP" command. Can someone please help?

```
sudo -i -u oracle mkdir /home/oracle/dump
sudo -i -u oracle cd /home/oracle/dump

JAR1="p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_1of7.zip"

JAR2="p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_2of7.zip"

folder="/home/oracle/database"

if  test -s "$JAR1"
 then
echo "$JAR1 exists"
else

sudo -i -u oracle 

wget XXXp://XXXXXX/XXXXXX/download/database/11.2.0.4/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_1of7.zip
fi

if  test -s "$JAR2"
 then
echo "$JAR2 exists"
else

sudo -i -u oracle 

wget XXXp://XXXXXXX/software/download/database/11.2.0.4/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_2of7.zip

fi

if  test -s "$folder"
 then
echo "$folder exists"
else

unzip /home/oracle/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_1of7.zip
unzip /home/oracle/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_2of7.zip

fi

sudo -i -u oracle ORACLE_HOSTNAME=`hostname`
sudo -i -u oracle ./runInstaller $ORACLE_HOSTNAME -silent -responseFile       /home/oracle/db.rsp

cd /opt/db/oraInventory
./orainstRoot.sh

cd /opt/db/oracle/11.2.0
./root.sh
```

Comment: it would be more readable if you put the code in a code block (to do that, insert 4 spaces before each line of code).

Comment: I think the problem is in this line: ``unzip /home/oracle/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_1of7.zip unzip /home/oracle/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_2of7.zip`` it looks like 2 commands are on the same line of code, so the second doesn't ever gets executed. To fix that, insert a semicolon in between commands or put them in separate lines.

Comment: unzip part is completed successfully. the script is exiting after unzip. both file referred to unzip has difference by one digit.